# How to make one value influence another value in the node editor if theres no input socket?

Tags: python, rendering, node-editor, compositing-nodes

I am currently trying to have a node setup where a value node output is linked to the Mix input of a Glare node. However, there's no input socket for the Mix input, only a number value. Is it possible to have the Value node influence the Mix input anyway?

Comment: Have you tried using a driver?

Comment: I don't really know what that is or how to use one, would you mind explaining it to me?